# Fire Parent event based upon child control event in WPF

Tags: wpf, events, user-controls

I have a user control that contains button as follows

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.myuseercontrol>
<Button Name="uxRemove" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="5" VerticalAlignment="Center"    
        HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="70" Content="Remove"
        Click="uxRemove_Click"/> 
</UserControl>
```

**the main window is as follows**:

```
<Window>
<stackpanel>
    <local:MyUserControl x:Name="uxPanel1" />
</stackpanel>
</Window>
```

Requirements:

1. I'd like to fire an event on the parent window when the event uxRemove_Click is fired at the usercontrl.
2. I'd like to add property Isenabled to the stackpanel "Usercontrol container" that will be based upon My usercontrol.IsEnabled property.

Comment: I found a good solution [Here](http://www.technologymaterial.com/Articles/WpfTabbedMDI.aspx?cat=wpf&aid=1).
are there any better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MDI-style solution may be a bit overcomplicated for what you are doing.

There is an [example of raising events from child controls to a parent window here](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201209/Blog/WPF-Bubbling-A-Command-From-A-Child-View/).

This is the basic gist:

- Declare a custom event type and a way to register handlers
- Raise the event in the child control wherever you need to
- Have a handler on the parent window that listens for the event

This is a much simpler solution for you than implementing an MDI style WPF application.